# How to get text paragraphs from a website: Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do web scraping with the help of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. But, the desired outcome is `null`.
My code is as follows:

```
def urlscrape(url):
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html')
    text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_='bg-white').find_all('p')]
    print(url)
    return text
```

The website is: `https://www.afghanistan-analysts.org/en/reports/war-and-peace/taleban-prisoners-release-are-the-latest-proposals-legal/`

I want all the `<p>` tags containing paragraphs to be extracted as texts.

Comment: `requests.get(url).status` is 403: you do not have permission to access that page. (Why haven't you checked the status?) You should probably pass user-agent header to `requests`.

Comment: the web page is accessible through the browser. I don't understand what it implies.

Comment: It implies that the web site can tell the difference between a browser and `requests`.

Comment: Can you give me some code of putting `user-agent`.. thing which I hardly understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
}
url = 'https://www.afghanistan-analysts.org/en/reports/war-and-peace/taleban-prisoners-release-are-the-latest-proposals-legal/'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
text = [p.text for p in soup.find_all('p')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
url="https://www.afghanistan-analysts.org/en/reports/war-and-peace/taleban-prisoners-release-are-the-latest-proposals-legal/"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
html = response.content
print(response.content)
```

Comment: I have had problems with this in the past - I thought it was time I worked out how to do this. Credit should be given to @DYZ for identifying the problem. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: The `user-agent` thing does not work for `Wall Street Journal`. Try this `https://www.wsj.com/articles/universities-abandon-reason-for-a-false-idea-of-empowerment-11597441181?mod=opinion_lead_pos6`